# List item in another class disappears when removing as passed instance

Tags: c#, list, oop, instance

I'm currently freakin out a little.
I'm passing a List to a method of another class and in that class I'm using a different variable name (encapsulated). But here it is:
When I remove an item from the list within the method the item disappears in the other variable as well!

Any suggetions what I'm doing wrong?

Here the code snippet:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   List<Vector> polygonPoints = new List<Vector>();

   private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
   {
      // Create Convex Hull of polygon Set
         QuickHull qh = new QuickHull();

      // here I pass the list to a method in the class QuickHull
      // here polygonPoints.Count = 5
         List<Vector> hullOfPoints = qh.quickHull(polygonPoints);
      // at this point I get polygonPoints.Count = 3

         ...
   }
}
```

different class QuickHull:

```
class QuickHull
{
    public List<Vector> quickHull(List<Vector> points)
    {
        List<Vector> convexHull = new List<Vector>();
        ...
        Vector A = points[minPoint];
        Vector B = points[maxPoint];

        convexHull.Add(A);
        convexHull.Add(B);

        // at this point 'polygonPoints' also looses these items
        points.Remove(A);
        points.Remove(B);

        ...
     }
}
```

I really don't know what to do because this was working all the time but from one moment to the other its not working anymore.

I'd really appreciate every suggetion.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because `List<T>` is a reference type, you're actually removing the item in the source object; not the copy. Refer http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx

Comment: how do I get a copy? and why did it work before?

Comment: *and why did it work before?*; It would have never worked.

Comment: I just found out why it was working before... I used a different list before which I didn't use after that operation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a `List<T>` to a method, you're passing a value which contains a reference to that list. That means that the argument you accept in your method, `points`, is pointing to the same list you instantiated higher up in the call chain.

If you want to pass a reference to a separate list, you'll need to create a new one:

```
List<Vector> hullOfPoints = qh.quickHull(polygonPoints.ToList());
```

You can read more on that in ["Passing Reference-Type Parameters"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6938f28.aspx):

> A variable of a reference type does not contain its data directly; it
>   contains a reference to its data. When you pass a reference-type
>   parameter by value, it is possible to change the data pointed to by
>   the reference, such as the value of a class member. However, you
>   cannot change the value of the reference itself;

Answer (score 1):

What you see is the expected behaviour.

A `List<T>` is a reference type, so when you pass it to a method it's the reference to the list that is passed.

Using a different variable name doesn't make it a new list. It's still the same list that you are referencing.

If you want a local copy of the list, you need to create a new list and copy the items into it. You can use the list constructor for this:

```
List<Vector> local = new List<Vector>(points);
```

---

You can also change the type that you send into the method:

```
public List<Vector> quickHull(IEnumerable<Vector> points)
```

By using the `IEnumerable<T>` interface instead of the `List<T>` class, you limit the use to only enumerating the list. You can still send a list into the method, but you can't change the list by mistake, and you can still use it to create the local copy.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you pass a '[reference](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx)' type and then change it. Instead you can create a NEW list (points) to avoid modifications of the previous input list (polygonPoints).